# Script to gather servers' information

Tags: server, bash, scripts

I need a script that will review a list of IPs for 200 servers and grab the Ubuntu OS information and deposit it to a file.

All my servers are Ubuntu versions between 14 and 18.

SSH is the notable method used to access each server using key-based authentication using RSA key generation.

Could I get some help with creating a script that accomplishes this?

The appended file can be placed at a generic nfs storage location (`server01:/file-storage /mnt/lsb-info`).

The script should do these tasks:

1. Review list of IPs from `IP_list.txt`
2. Log in to each server
3. Execute command: `lsb_release -a`
4. Append info to `LSB_Release_Info.txt`

Comment: @EliahKagan - I appreciate your consideration looking into this. All of the servers are Ubuntu ranging between versions 14 and 18, and yes, I use SSH to login to each server. I have about 200 servers I need to log into and grab this information. Its tedious, so I'm hoping I can script it to help end the suffering. :-) And actually, I only need the OS version not the entire 'lsb_release -a' info, so if you know how to reduce that down to IP-OSversion that would be ideal.

Comment: `cat /etc/lsb-release` seems to be a possible command if, as @EliahKagan says, `lsb_release` is not available.

Comment: Have you ever used any scripting language before?

Comment: @CrashFive Add the information you provided in the above comment to the question, [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1167754/edit) it.

Comment: @guillermochamorro - done

Comment: @user535733 - not really. i could write a simple bash script that execute simple commands, but when you get into nesting and else-ifs, i'm ignorant.

Comment: @EliahKagan - done, any additional info i can provide you?

Comment: It *could* be as simple as installing `pssh` and then running `parallel-ssh -h IP_list.txt -P lsb_release -r > LSB_Release_Info.txt`

Comment: @steeldriver Would you be willing to post an answer about that? I believe that's at least as good as the `xargs` method I showed in my answer, and very likely better.

Comment: Reviewers: [This is not *off-topic*](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/13807) and, considering it can be done in one line, I don't see how it would be *too broad*. Also: unlike far too many questions on the site, the OP made substantial and effective efforts to add information on request, which led to an answer. (I've deleted my earlier comments requesting information, but you can check the edit history. Details on how the servers are accessed and how logins performed were promptly and helpfully given.) So for anyone who thinks this is a "gimme the code" or otherwise low-effort question: it is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using key-based authentication with SSH, it is easy to automate running a command on many machines. You can write a simple script to do this, but you don't really need to. You can do it with a single command, something like:

```bash
xargs -a IP_list.txt -d'\n' -I{} ssh {} 'printf "\n%s:\n" {}; lsb_release -a' | tee -a LSB_Release_Info.txt
```

This runs one `ssh` command for each line of `IP_list.txt`, plugging the line in for `{}`. For this to work, each line should be an IP address or hostname of a server you want to SSH to. Suppose, for example, that `IP_list.txt` contains the line `192.168.10.2`. Then the SSH command that `xargs` runs for that line is:

```bash
ssh 192.168.10.2 'printf "\n%s:\n" 192.168.10.2; lsb_release -a'
```

What `ssh` does with that command is to attempt to connect to 192.168.10.2 and to execute this code in a non-interactive shell:

```bash
printf "\n%s:\n" 192.168.10.2; lsb_release -a
```

That consists of two commands. The first prints a blank line followed by the line `192.168.10.2:`. The second is `lsb_release -a`.

The `ssh` command can only succeed if you are logging in with the correct credentials:

- As I've written it, your *local* username will be used. If that's not correct, you'll have to modify the command accordingly. For example, if all the machines have the same username as one another--e.g., `foo`--then you'd write `ssh foo@{}` in place of `ssh {}`.
- As you probably know, you'll need to cache your decrypted private key with an authentication agent, to avoid needing to type your local SSH key passphrase in for each `ssh` command. My guess is that you have this set up already; if not, see `man ssh-agent`. (Likely it is sufficient to run `eval "$(ssh-agent)"` followed by `ssh-add`, and enter your passphrase.)

Piping the output of that `xargs` command with the `|` operator to `tee -a LSB_Release_Info.txt` *shows* you the output while also *appending* it to the (local) file `LSB_Release_Info.txt`. **Error messages are not included in the file; those will only be shown to you.** If you wanted to include them in the output file, you could use `|&` instead of `|`, but you're very unlikely to want them. More likely, you might *only* want to see error messages, in which case you can use `>>LSB_Release_Info.txt` instead of `| tee -a LSB_Release_Info.txt`--that is, just redirect to the file instead of piping to `tee`. Note that if you run `tee` without `-a`, or if you use `>` instead of `>>`, then you are *overwriting* `LSB_Release_info.txt` instead of appending to it.

I suggest testing this out first with an input file consisting of just a few IP addresses. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> usually succeeds at stopping a long-running command, but I still suggest doing a bit of testing to get it right before running it for all your servers. For example, to write this answer I tested this on my local network with four IP addresses, and got output to my terminal (and in `LSB_Release_Info.txt`) like this:

```
192.168.10.2:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

192.168.10.4:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

192.168.203.128:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Eoan Ermine (development branch)
Release:        19.10
Codename:       eoan

192.168.31.130:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

That's what the output should look like with the command given above. You can adjust the command accordingly, then run it on all two hundred servers once it produces the output format you want.

Comment: thank you for this.